# Angular - ngFor over collection of objects that have an array property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I have a class like this:

```
export class TableColumn {
  columnName: string;
  isToFilter: boolean;
  isToSort: boolean;
  isLink: boolean;
  linkUrl: string;
  columnData: any[];

constructor(
    columnName: string,
    isToFilter: boolean,
    isToSort: boolean,
    isLink: boolean,
    linkUrl: string,
    columnData: any[]) {
    this.columnName = columnName;
    this.isToFilter = isToFilter;
    this.isToSort = isToSort;
    this.isLink = isLink;
    this.linkUrl = linkUrl;
    this.columnData = columnData;
  }
}
```

You can see there is an array property here - `columnData`. My problem is when I use `*ngFor` directive to iterate over array of instances of this class like this:

```
 ngFor="let column of tableColumns"
```

the directive iterate not only through content of `tableColumns` but through content of `columnData` property in every instance as well.

I would like to know how to not iterate through content of property `columnData`.

Comment: Can you share your template snippet?

Comment: <div *ngFor="let column of tableColumns">
  {{column}}
</div>

Comment: @bambaniasz You want to say that `column` variable get's values from `ColumnData` of each `tableColumn` ?

Comment: ngFor iterate over columData properties when I use it like this<div *ngFor="let column of tableColumns"> {{column}} </div>. and tableColumns is an array of TableColumn objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying you have an array of the `TableColumn` objects, and you want to loop over those, and then inside each of them also loop over the `columnData` array?

First, just so you know, you can write your class object like this to simplify things.  It compiles down to the exact same JavaScript. [Look at this page to see what I mean](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20TableColumnComplex%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20columnName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20isToFilter%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20isToSort%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20isLink%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20linkUrl%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20columnData%3A%20any%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconstructor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20columnName%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isToFilter%3A%20boolean%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isToSort%3A%20boolean%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20isLink%3A%20boolean%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20linkUrl%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20columnData%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.columnName%20%3D%20columnName%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.isToFilter%20%3D%20isToFilter%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.isToSort%20%3D%20isToSort%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.isLink%20%3D%20isLink%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.linkUrl%20%3D%20linkUrl%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.columnData%20%3D%20columnData%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F---------------------%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TableColumnSimple%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20columnName%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20isToFilter%3A%20boolean%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20isToSort%3A%20boolean%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20isLink%3A%20boolean%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20linkUrl%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20columnData%3A%20any%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

```
export class TableColumn {
    constructor(
        public columnName: string,
        public isToFilter: boolean,
        public isToSort: boolean,
        public isLink: boolean,
        public linkUrl: string,
        public columnData: any[]
    ) { }
}
```

With some sample data like this in our controller:

```
public tableColumnList = [
  new TableColumn('one', true, true, true, 'google.com', [1,2,3]),
  new TableColumn('two', true, true, true, 'google.com', [4,5,6, 7, 8]),
  new TableColumn('three', true, true, true, 'google.com', [9, 10, 11])
];
```

You can just use nested `*ngFor` directives, like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let tc of tableColumnList">
  <h4>{{tc.name}}</h4>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let data of tc.columnData">
      {{data}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```